# Неграмотный и безграмотный

Tags: синонимы

Интересно, что это слова, как я понимаю, изначально бывшие синонимами, теперь имеют разное значение. Неграмотный - тот, кто по той или иной причине не знает грамоты, а безграмотный - тот, кто пишет с кучей ошибок.
Интересно, почему так? Или, так сказать, просто сложилось?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С темой грамотности связаны несколько  прилагательных, которые различаются  оттенками значений.

Когда мы говорим, что в дореволюционной России  крестьяне были НЕГРАМОТНЫМИ или МАЛОГРАМОТНЫМИ,   это означает, что  они  были не обучены грамоте или обучены плохо.  В наше время НЕГРАМОТНЫМИ или БЕЗГРАМОТНЫМИ мы обычно называем  людей, которые пишут неграмотно,  но и в этом значении слова  не являются полными синонимами.  «НЕГРАМОТНЫЙ»  – это, скорее,  стилистически нейтральное слово, а слово «БЕЗГРАМОТНЫЙ»  имеет  дополнительную негативную оценку  или  повышенную степень признака, то есть  означает «совершенно неграмотный, пишущий с большим количеством ошибок».

Различие значений можно объяснить следующим образом. «Неграмотный» (способ образования грамотный →неграмотный)  – это  не являющийся грамотным, не  имеющий отношения к грамоте, а безграмотный (грамота →безграмотный) – это не владеющий грамотой.

Приставки БЕЗ и НЕ в парном варианте часто используются  для образования прилагательных или существительных: иногда  слова с этими приставками отличаются друг от друга по значению (ненадежный – безнадежный, неумный – безумный), в других же случаях приставка  БЕЗ, по сравнению с приставкой НЕ,  усиливает признак: неверие – безверие, нерадостный – безрадостный, незаконный – беззаконный .

Во всех приведенных примерах  различие в значениях строится по одному образцу:  приставка НЕ  отрицает признак (неопасный – не является опасным), а приставка БЕЗ называет признак, отрицающий предмет (безопасный – не содержит опасности).